# How to find common substring in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I got the following DataFrame:

| Solution Name | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| Cleanser | ContentA |
| Cleanser(1+2) | ContentA |
| Cleanserx3 | ContentB |
| Trial | ContentC |
| Incremental Trial | ContentC |

So as you can see from the above, there are common substring in the column 'Solution Name'

Expected Result:

| Solution Name | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| Cleanser | ContentA |
| Cleanser | ContentB |
| Trial | ContentC |

If the `Content` is different, the row will still be here. Just the cells in column `Solution Name` are changed.

Comment: Most users here probably will not be able to read the contents of the "Solution Name" column. Also, now it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe try to rephrase the question in a way where you show how you would like to go from the source to the expected result (in words, not in code).

Answer (score 0):

You can just google around "find common substrings", and it is not difficult. Then work around with pandas to find your ideal table representation.

Here is one way to work around

```py
from suffix_trees import STree
def find_common(l):
    common = STree.STree(list(l['Solution Name']))
    return common.lcs()

a = pd.DataFrame({
    'Solution Name': ['Cleanser', 'Cleanser(1+2)', 'Cleanserx3', 'Trial', 'Incremental Trial'],
    'Detail': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
})
result = pd.DataFrame(a.groupby('Detail').apply(find_common), columns=['Solution Name']).reset_index()[['Solution Name', 'Detail']]
display(result)
```

Comment: However, if I changed the 'Solution Name'  to Chinese, this does not work

Comment: Let said `'24小時', '24小時x3', '24小時(1+2)'`replace `'Cleanser', 'Cleanser(1+2)', 'Cleanserx3'`. This does not work

Comment: @Hang It worked for me. When you say it does not work, can you also specify the Error message?

Comment: There is no Error message, however, the dataframe is not same as I expected. When I use Chinese words, the second cellof column "Solution Name" is `24小時(1+2)` instead of `24小時`

Comment: @Hang That's weird.  It might be a problem of your dataframe header. If you read the dataset with CSV, it can cause a problem. Try looking at the "header" argument in pandas doc

Comment: I do read it through csv

Comment: Might I ask what is your version of pandas

Comment: I guess it is because you are using `groupby`. If the values in `Detail` is different, the function cannot compare the string in `Solution Name`

Comment: @Hang I am using 1.4.2. However, I don't think it's the main issue here. Yes, to use `groupby` you need to have values that are the same. I did it because I assume you have unique values in the  `Detail` column. Unfortunately, I can only help you this far...